# how to create symbolic link to all my sub folders to another folder?

Tags: ubuntu, symbolic-link

I know I can use for loop for it but it will fail when any new folder will come, if is there any good alternative to create symbolic link of all my sub folder which can take care if any new folder will be created then it will be linked also...

Answer (score 0):

why not just symlink to the folder above ?

Comment: as each folder is a python module, and application I use is searching for python modules and importing it. I mean if I use the command line --addons-path = ../../addons it will use all modules inside this folder as addons